# unattainable item in dropdown menu ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, drop-down-menu

the page : http://medisra.sideradesign.com/
on the second menu from the left, there is a dropdown. I am not able to click on the last 3 items of the submenu because they disappear before I get a chance.
it seems it has something to do with the position of the menu. for example, if I increase the height of the header container, I'm able to click the menu items.

any help appreciated

thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct reason for this problem is that the page is being set to render in IE7 mode via the HTTP response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
..
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
..
```

This header is effectively turning IE8 into IE7, which isn't great. The purpose of [`X-UA-Compatible`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8#Compatibility_mode) is to provide a quick way to help older pages designed for IE7 still look acceptable in IE8.

If you remove this header, the page looks *almost* correct in IE8 (just a couple of minor display problems; they look relatively easy to fix).

Comment: and how could I do that? it doesn't seem to be coded in the source

Comment: I guess it's being put in there through a `.htaccess` file. Do you have one?

Comment: I accepted the answer even though I'm not sure it's the right one :)

Comment: the .htaccess only contains this : 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: My answer is "correct", it's just a matter of finding where that header is coming from. I see it's not in your `.htaccess` file. I recommend making another question like this: "I have a site http://medisra.sideradesign.com/ and it doesn't look correct in IE8, because this is in the HTTP response headers: `X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7`. The problem is, I don't know where this header is coming from. Any ideas?" The benefit of making a new question is that you will get fresh people thinking on the idea of where that header is coming from, instead of just me.

Comment: how do you see the HTTP response headers?

Comment: There are a few different ways, but in this case I used a program called [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). An easier way for you could be to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp).