# background hidden by selectivizr script in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, background

the page : http://medisra.sideradesign.com/lechenie/
under the header, there is a 3 column list of links with blue star bullets. it has a shadow background which fades out at the bottom.
in IE8, it is cut off near the top. If I disable selectivizr, it appears normally.
is this a z-index issue?
any ideas for fixing this?
thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the same issue as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803503/unattainable-item-in-dropdown-menu-ie8).

If you remove the `X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7` response header, it's fixed.

I'm testing this by using IE's Developer Tools, and switching the page into "IE8 Standards" mode - when I do this, the problem is fixed.

Comment: I see, I changed the page to IE8 standards and it works. maybe there's a CSS error that's causing the IE7 mode?

Comment: The IE7 mode is caused by the presence of the `X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7` HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to selectivizr 1.0.1 - it fixes an issue with relative URLs in style sheets